# Capitalization of official divisions of an organization

Tags: grammar, terminology, capitalization

Some organizations, like sects, divide themselves into parts—usually, there are two two parts, and those parts are called "outer sect" and "inner sect". These aren't simply an euphemistic term, like "inner city", but an actual, official division done by the organization itself. This division is both physical and hierarchical. The outer sect is physically separated from the inner sect (they correspond to specific physical areas), and "inner-sect member" and "outer-sect member" are official positions, with the former being hierarchically higher than the latter. In this case, are "outer sect" and "inner sect" actually supposed to be written as "Outer Sect" and "Inner Sect"? And, if that's the case, would it mean that the correct way to refer to their members is actually "Inner-Sect member" and "Outer-Sect member"?

I believe that, in some companies, divisions such as the "Sales Division" are capitalized, so would "outer sect" and "inner sect" fall under the same category?

Comment: This is a question for what is called an organization's style sheet. It is not an English question per se. That said, you use of sect is somewhat odd.

Comment: @Lambie Well, yes, this would fall under that category, but had I asked this in a place where such organization's style sheet are the primary focus, I'd mostly get answers that are based on preference (it's about _style_, after all). However, I wanted to know if there was a capitalization rule that, although not specific to my situation, could still be applied to it, which is why I asked it here. I'm looking for an answer based on grammar, not style. As for my use of sect, I'm actually basing myself on the Chinese concept of sect, not the Western one.

Comment: No, there are no capitalization rules for organization's stuff i.e. written stuff. There are only capitalization rules for the language in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this case, are "outer sect" and "inner sect" actually supposed to be written as "Outer Sect" and "Inner Sect"?

If the members themselves recognise these divisions and use them as names to refer to each of the divisions of the sect, then "Yes, they are capitalised."

Comment: And would this mean that I would likewise capitalize "Inner-Sect disciple" (as opposed to inner-sect disciple) and "Outer-Sect disciple" (as opposed to outer-sect disciple) or would that be a question of preference/style?

Comment: It's style. The Church of England is often said to be divided into the Low Church (Protestant emphasis, against ritual) and the High Church (Catholic style, favouring ritual). In the _Church Times_, you can find "strongly Evangelical, “anti-Romanist”, and low-church" and "a kind of Low Church, open-Evangelical place".

Comment: @Rustpen *And would this mean that I would likewise capitalize "Inner-Sect disciple"* Yes, of course.